# How can I move polynomial items in an equation to one side?

Tags: javascript, math, polynomial-math

So I have a polynomial equation equivalent in js in a string which I can eval. (assuming the eval execution is safe) for example

```
2 * x + 3 * y - z = 0;
```

The above is a string and with appropriate scope where x, y and z are defined, I can eval the above string and it will give me the result. I want to make it so that I can find the value of x where others are given. So my desired output would be.

```
x = (z - 3 * y) / 2;
```

Is it possible to get the above string? if not then is it possible to just find the value of x when y and z are given? I know this sounds like homework but it isn't.

Comment: Will it *always* be in the form "a * x + b * y - z = 0", with no possibility of deviation?

Comment: it can use math.pow, or math.log or math.sin, cos, tan. that's pretty much it.

Comment: Would a 'search' algorithm be a suitable solution, or are you looking at non-integer solutions (as your answer does imply that parsing the string directly would be complex)?

Comment: search algorithm as in regex? I would rather solve it without regex because it can get very complicated to account for all the Math.* functions in regex.

Comment: No, a mathematical search, to narrow down the value of X to between bounds and (if integer) a single value.

Comment: oh a single value. Not bounds, I am trying to solve gauss seidel equations in visual manner, like how you would solve it on paper, step by step, otherwise finding the solution is pretty easy, printing each step is more dificult than I thought it would be

Comment: If you know the expression is linear in x (i. e. adding 1 to x will add/subtract a constant amount from the result) and the RHS is alwas "= 0" you can evaluate LHS for (1,y,z) and (0,y,z) and then find x by interpolation. If not, you'd need some more complex parsing of the expression...

Comment: @mihi I think that is exactly what kol did in his answer.

Comment: @mihi That's what I was thinking (although linearity is being ruled out by mention of sin etc).

Comment: @AdrianWragg oh, I am not very good with math, this is a part of a larger interface that solves other methods like bisection and newton raphson. And they use sin/cos, so I am hoping to code it to at least fail gracefully if it encounters something which it can't handle. So I think sin/cos wont be used in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x, y, z, r1, r2, a, b,
    eq = "2 * x + 3 * y - z = 0;";

console.clear();
eq = eq.replace(" = 0;", "");
y = 12; z = 34;
x = 1; r1 = eval(eq);
x = 2; r2 = eval(eq);
a = r2 - r1; b = r1 - a; x = -b / a;
console.log(x);
```

Or, if you need the solution formula as a string:

```
var eq = "2 * x + 3 * y - z = 0;", eq2,
    match, a, b, c, x, y, z;

function process(prefix) {
    prefix = prefix.replace(/[\s\*]/g, "");
    switch (prefix) {
        case "" : return +1;
        case "+": return +1;
        case "-": return -1;
        default : return +prefix;
    }
}

console.clear();
match = eq.match(/^([^x]*)x([^y]*)y([^z]*)z ?= ?0;$/);
if (match === null || match.length !== 4)
    console.log("Invalid equation");
else {
    a = process(match[1]);
    b = process(match[2]);
    c = process(match[3]);
    eq2 = "(" + (-b) + " * y + " + (-c) + " * z) / " + a; 
    console.log(eq2);
    y = 12; z = 34;
    x = eval(eq2);
    console.log(x);
}
```

`eq2` will be `(-3 * y + 1 * z) / 2`

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly,

To find the value of x:

Evaluate the remaining expression, change its sign, and divide it by x's coefficient (if it's not zero).

To get the string array,

Change the sign of each of the remaining coefficients and divide each by x's coefficient.

EDIT: As already suggested,

```
say b = exp(0,y,z), a = exp(1,0,0).
x = -b/a
```

Comment: but how do I get the remaining expression? It's a string. If I execute it without x, it will say x is undefined.